# P0340 code, even after camshaft sensor replacement [Solved]

Tags: engine, honda, obd-ii, obd, cam-position-sensor

I drive a 2004 Honda Civic ex coupe manual with ABS, engine code D17A2 (SOHC, Vtec)

I was driving my car and slowly revved up to 7krpm (smart, I realize) and suddenly my car lost power until 3500rpm and had a check engine light. It still drove, just not at high rpm. I went to the autoparts store, checked the code, and after googling I concluded it was the camshaft position sensor, although I don't recall exactly what that code was. I bought the sensor for $60, hoping I was paying for a quality part.
I replaced the sensor, but my engine light was still on. However, while I drove back to the auto parts store, I took my car up to 5k rpm with no signs of limp mode. I checked the code with the store's OBDII, and this time it said:

P0340 ENG
camshaft position sensor A circuit
CURRENT

P0340 Mod $11
Camshaft position sensor A circuit (Bank 1 or single sensor)
CONFIRMED

Any ideas what I should try next? I thought for sure this code was asking me to replace the sensor.

Thanks for reading

Edit: While my new OBDII thing was still in the mail, my engine light turned itself off after driving a bit. I assume the code just needed clearing

Comment: I'm not sure there is a problem. Sometimes check engine lights and codes persist after the problem is fixed and you have to clear them. I suggest you clear the codes and check engine light and see if the messages come back.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried clearing the code yet, I didn't actually know I needed to do that. I'll update when I get a chance to test it out